# Enable Custom Priority Option for MX Records in Plesk Control Panel

Tags: dns, plesk, mx-record

I have installed the plesk panel in my VPS for managing my websites.

Now i want to add MX Record with Priority of **1**. But there is no option available to select **1**.

I can't verify without add the MX Record with priority 1.

Please help me to add the priority 1 for MX.

[image: Please Check this Image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Plesk, but it's quite common for domain hosts to have different settings for priority.

Lower the number has higher in priority in MX record. Since your Plesk panel doesn't have the option for priority 1, you can set it to highest (0). [G Suite's Plesk guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9174449?hl=en&ref_topic=4446024) for MX record also has a similar case and they suggests the same.

Comment: Gsuite doesn't allow to verify without the MX Record with the priority 1. I have added it by edit the domain's dns configuration file via SSH.